# Copy formatted text between PDF documents, empty unicode mapping for font

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox, text-extraction

I'm using `PDFBox` 2.0.8 for pdf content extraction, converting it to `JSON` and then building a new document from created JSON (to clean possible vulnerabilities). I've extended `PDFTextStripper` class for getting font info:

`PDFont font = textPosition.getFont() // it is embedded font`

Now I'm trying to write just the same extracted character with its font to new pdf document:

`contentStream.setFont(font, 16);`

`contentStream.showText(text);`

and I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+004A in font HLOXAY+Birka-SemiBoldItalic` exception on the second line.

The text I want to write is "John Whitington" from the third page of a "PDF Explained" book.

I've already read that it is because of current font doesn't have a Unicode mapping. But as I understand if this text is displayed in all readers there should be a way for copying it to another pdf.

I just want to full copy text and fonts info between documents.

Sorry if this duplicates any question here, but after a few days of searching, I still can't find an acceptable solution. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Obviously it won't work easily with PDFBox if the unicode is missing, because the unicode is needed for showing text. IMHO your whole strategy is wrong; a better one would be to strip a PDF file of any javascript and file attachments. PDF files are more than just text.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks for your answer. I'm very new to pdf format structure and pdfbox. So are the scripts and file attachments the only possible vulnerability sources in pdf?

Comment: I googled a bit... there's also launch actions. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64052/can-a-pdf-file-contain-a-virus The problem is that everything mentioned can also have legit purposes. For example, javascript is useful for form filling, to make field checks or field changes based on user clicks.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks again for help. I need probably to review my strategy.

Comment: *"I'm very new to pdf format structure and pdfbox."* - In that case there is much learning ahead of you before you can seriously work on your task. Please be aware that existing PDF libraries usually are designed to allow users to create new PDFs from scratch or add arbitrary content to existing PDFs; furthermore to manipulate forms (read, fill-in, flatten) and to extract text or images. Usually they do not contain high-level code, though, to analyze all the PDF contents. That can be done using the low-level methods, yes, but to use them properly some knowledge about PDF internals is required.